# Create a multi-Dimensional array of structs on a heap?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am trying to declare a 3-dimensional array of structs on a heap.

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct data
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

And I have:

```
typedef struct data data_t;
```

Also the dimensions are given as:

```
int dim1, dim2, dim3;
```

I just can't figure out a way to malloc a 3-D array of structs

Comment: What version of standard are you using ? Some newer versions of C have better features that apply for your question.

Comment: `malloc` and heap allocated variables ( a.k.a. "dynamic allocated variables" ) require pointers, regardless if the variables are arrays or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
data_t ***arr;

arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * dim1);
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
    arr[i] =  malloc(sizeof(*arr[i]) * dim2);
    for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
        arr[i][j] =  malloc(sizeof(*arr[i][j]) * dim3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `sizeof(*arr[i])` and `sizeof(*arr[i][j])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop for memory allocation.

```
data_t ***3d_arrOfStruct = malloc(dim1*sizeof(data_t **); 
for(int i = 0; i < dim2; i++)
{
      3d_arrOfStruct[i] = malloc(dim2*sizeof(data_t *); 
      for(int j = 0; i < dim2; j++)
      {
           3d_arrOfStruct[i][j] = malloc(dim3*sizeof(data_t); 
      }
}
```

Note that this is not gonna allocate continuous memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your multi-dimensional array is not "jagged" (as by your question it is not), then since C99<sup>1</sup> you can simply use only one `malloc` call:

```
data_t (*p)[dim2][dim3] = malloc(dim1 * sizeof *p);
```

The `sizeof *p` already "knows" size of each sub-dimension, so there is no need to repeat `dim2` and `dim3` on the right side. However, if really want to repeat yourself, the equivalent call would be:

```
data_t (*p)[dim2][dim3] = malloc(dim1 * dim2 * dim3 * sizeof p[0][0][0]);
```

or even:

```
data_t (*p)[dim2][dim3] = malloc(dim1 * dim2 * dim3 * sizeof(data_t));
```

You gain additional advantage of such approach, which is that only one `free` call is needed to clean it as-a-whole.

Here is workable solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

typedef struct data data_t;

int main(void)
{
    int dim1 = 1, dim2 = 2, dim3 = 3;

    data_t (*p)[dim2][dim3] = malloc(dim1 * sizeof *p);

    p[0][0][0].x = 0;
    p[0][0][0].y = 0;

    printf("%f\n", p[0][0][0].x);

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>1) Assuming that array's sizes are not known compile-time. In other words they are not *constant expressions*, but in your question `dim1`, `dim2` and `dim3` are explicitely stated as variables.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Simplest and probably fastest would be to use 1d array:

```
data* cube = (data*)malloc(dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(data));

data GetItem(int x, int y, int z)
{
   auto index = x + y * dim1 + z * dim1 * dim2;
   return cube[index];
}
```

Comment: @Milan. I agree with Alter Mann. Your solution may be good idea if it was "C++", but, the question is tagged (Plain) "C"

Comment: Oh I missed it is C, my apology, than just use malloc with the same approach. I had filter on questions for c++, didn't realise it is showing questions from "other" languages as well.